# Replace non-numeric characters in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

**question editted to avoid duplication**

I have a pandas dataframe with `A, B, C, D , E` columns:

```
A B C D E

X 2 3 - 5

Y Â 3 4 Â

Z - - Â 5
```

I would like to remove all non-machine readable characters (`Â`) and non-numeric characters (`-`) from column `B` onwards and replace them with `NaN`.

Thanks

Comment: I have edited this question to avoid duplication, could you re-open it please?

Answer (score 2):

Using `where`

```
df.where(df.applymap(
    lambda x: str(x).isdigit()
))
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. A followup; if I only wanted to remove non-machine readable characters from the frame (i.e. keep standard text), how would I modify this?